# Rails 4 collection_select with specific locale variable input parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a legacy database with a table country that has country names in different languages.

The columns are:

```
country_de
country_en
country_fr
country_it
```

My app uses i18n.locale and now I want to populate the country collection_select with the specific locale parameters.

I know I could use a simple if else or switch and set the params statically but is there a way to *do this in one line?*

**Working** example for English:

```
<%= f.collection_select :country_id, Country.order('country_en ASC'), :id, :country_en, {prompt: t("select_country")} %>
```

What I am trying at the moment and is **not working** is this:

```
<%= f.collection_select :country_id, Country.order('country_'+locale.to_s+' ASC'), :id, "country_"+locale.to_s+"".to_sym , {prompt: t("select_country")} %>
```

Where locale will be `de`, `en`, `it`, or `fr` of course.

The error that I have is:

```
no implicit conversion of Symbol into String
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
"country_"+locale.to_s+"".to_sym
```

With:

```
"country_#{locale}".to_sym
```

Better use string interpolation, which implicitly calls to_s

Comment: btw what is the difference between " and ' in ruby? I assume " is explicitly String but what is ' then?

Comment: with single quotes you will not be able to interpolate strings. And also, if you will use "\n" - you get a special character (newline), and '\n' - will get you '\n'

Comment: Ok so it is more like string escaping ... I'll google it thanks for the explanation